# Get data from a table associated with a pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have a many many relationship from which comes a middle table

users

quotes

user_quote (this is the intermediate)

From this intermediate table I have another one to many relationship with another table (quotes_time)

Image database schema

[ER DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bivCL.png)

User model:

```
    public function quotes()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quote::class, 'quote_user');
 }
```

Quote model:

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'quote_user');
}
```

How can I get the data from the quotes_time table?

In the users controller I have this:

```
 $users = User::with('latestQuotes','latestQuotes.vehicle')->filter($request);
```

What I really need is to get quotes_time data from users

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 2 options.

## 1. Accessing the BelongsTo relationship from the Pivot model.

User model:

```php
public function quotes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quote::class, 'quote_user')->using(QuoteUser::class);
}
```

Quote model:

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'quote_user')->using(QuoteUser::class);
}
```

QuoteUser Pivot Model

```php
class QuoteUser extends Pivot
{
    public function time()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(QuoteTime::class, 'user_quotes_id');
    }
}
```

```php
$users = User::with('quotes')->get();

foreach ($user->quotes as $quote) {
    $quote->pivot->time->start;
}
```

## 2. Using a hasManyThrough relationship between User and QuoteTime (or Quote and QuoteTime)

User model:

```php
public function quotes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quote::class, 'quote_user')->using(QuoteUser::class);
}

public function quoteTimes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(QuoteTime::class, QuoteUser::class);
}
```

Quote model:

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'quote_user')->using(QuoteUser::class);
}

public function quoteTimes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(QuoteTime::class, QuoteUser::class);
}
```

```php
$users = User::with('quoteTimes')->get();

foreach ($user->quotes_times as $quote_time) {
    $quote_time->start;
}
// or
$user = User::with('quotes.quoteTimes')->get();

foreach ($user->quotes as $quote) {
    $quote->quote_times->...
}
```